# Why I have ugly spaces in my table

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
   <script type='text/javascript' src='js/myTasks.js'></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/walk.css">
      <TITLE>Your Tasks</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
    <div class="screenSection">
        <div class="sectionHeader">
            <p>Your Tasks</p>
        </div>
        <div class="lines">        

        <table class="dataTable" id="CADataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 15em;"> Project name</th>
        <th style="width: 7em;"> Number</th>        
        <th style="width: 50em;"> description</th>
        <th style="width: 5em;"></th>
    </tr>   
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Assimilation">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" data-bind="value: Name" style="width: 15em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Num" data-bind="value: Num" style="width: 7em;"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Desc" data-bind="value: Desc" style="width: 50em;"></td>
        <td style="width: 5em;">
                <img src="img/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: $root.removeAssimilation"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="export" class="button" data-bind="click: newAssimilation">Add new row</button>


        </div>
    </div>
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Now everything is ok, but when I press the add new row button, I'm getting this ugly thing:

[image]

I'm using this css:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

.formElement { height: auto; margin: 0 0.4em; padding: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em; min-width: 40%; display: inline-block;}
.formElement label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    margin: 0.8em 0 0.1em 0.15em;
    width: 17.89em;
}
.formElement textarea { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 2px; font-size: 1.15em; }
.formElement span { font-size: 1.05em; font-weight: bold; }
.lines { overflow: hidden; }
#commentInformation .formElement { width: 80%; }
input[type="text"] { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding: 0.2em; height: 22px; width: 250px }
fileSelection { width: 50em; height: 30px; }
input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff; outline: none; }
td
{
    background: #A9D0F5;
    text-align: center;
    height:2em;
}
th
{
    height:2em;
}

.trClass
{
height:2em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

table
{
    width: 98%;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    clear: both;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove the blue space.

I'm 1000% sure that I'm making a small mistake somewhere, but it is my first css try. I'm a backend developer and it is really hard for me to spot any non sense things in the code. Please help me!

**EDIT:**

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/37sbw/2/)

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: @frenchie the blue space should not be there.

Comment: reset the css like `td {padding: 0; margin: 0}` and remove `text-align:center` in td.

Comment: Try this once 
table.dataTable{width:auto !important}

Comment: If I remove your `height` settings the space goes away.

Comment: @Josh Can you show me the fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/37sbw/3/ - Removing that height specification results in a consistent thin blue line (which is what I assume you're trying to accomplish). In general there's a lot of CSS going on here...looks like a lot applies to other parts of your page, but I'd personally try to remove as much as possible to simplify it.

Comment: @Josh It looks the same as the 1st screenshot once I uploaded it on the server. :(

Comment: What browser are you using? I assume you want the blue line since you specified the color...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/37sbw/5/

you need to remove the

```
       background: #A9D0F5;
```

applied for td

keep it like this

```
 td
 {
    //background: #A9D0F5;
    text-align: center;
    height:2em;
 }
```

I have even added

```
  cellspacing="0px"
```

to the table to remove the spacing between the cells.

If cellspacing is not applied then go for this

```
      table
     {
       border-spacing:0px;
     }
```

Comment: For some reason when I upload it to my server the ` cellspacing="0px" ` is not applying.

Comment: try this. table { border-collapse: collapse; }

Comment: No luck. :( CSS is the hardest thing ever invented!

Comment: m sure this will help you border-spacing:0px;

Comment: I spoted the problem. It is in: `width: 98%;` Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Make Cell Spacing  & Cell Padding as 0px

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean that the input field doesn't take up all the parent's width.

You have specified inline-style. This will override the CSS you've put in a seperate sheet.

```
<td><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" data-bind="value: Name" style="width: 15em;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Num" data-bind="value: Num" style="width: 7em;"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Desc" data-bind="value: Desc" style="width: 50em;"></td>
<td style="width: 5em;">
        <img src="img/close.jpg" alt="Close" data-bind="click: $root.removeAssimilation"> 
</td>
```

Get rid of all the occurences of `style=""` and it should work as you expect it to work.

Additionally, change your CSS to this:

```
input[type="text"] {width: 100%;}
```

Comment: After changing the css and removing the `style` from the `HTML` it looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/zaclij0s3/full/

Answer (score 0):

Set `border-spacing`  of your table to 0:

```
table {
   width: 98%;
   font-size: 1.2em;
   clear: both;
   border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This will get rid of your white space between the cells.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37sbw/6/)**